# Hiding SharePoint 2013 Lists Tile inside Site Contents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a requirement from user, to hide sharepoint lists / libraries from site contents based on the permission. If a user does not have permission in the list / library, then the icon / tile will disappear from the site contents page.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This is how it works out of the box - if the user doesn't have permission, the list will not visible on site contents

Comment: Isn't this available out of the box?

Comment: Hmm.. it does not seem so. I have a user named X who has Design permission, and I have a list Z who stop inheriting permissions, and add only Site Owner (Full Control) as the only one group who have permission on that list (of course X is not a member of that group). But when X open the site contents page, he still could see the Z list. But when I tried to open the list, the lack of permission error is shown (Sorry, you don't have access to this page).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make sure you have the right permissions is to delete existing permissions and add the desired permissions you want.

So in your case:

1) Go to the Document Library -> Library Permissions

2) Stop inheriting permissions

3) Select all permissions and choose 'Remove User Permissions' from the Ribbon

4) From the Ribbon, select 'Grant Permissions'

5) In the dialog, select your SharePoint Group and select the appropriate user permissions from the 'Grant users permissions directly' choices

Now try to login with less privilege users, you won't see list/library displayed in site content.Same is case with Quick Launch Also

The Quick Launch displays only the libraries that the logged in user has access to. Other libraries are automatically hidden.

Comment: Hmm.. I've tried that but no luck. I have a user named X who has Design permission, and I have a list Z who stop inheriting permissions, and add only Site Owner (Full Control) as the only one group who have permission on that list (of course X is not a member of that group). But when X open the site contents page, he still could see the Z list. But when I tried to open the list, the lack of permission error is shown (Sorry, you don't have access to this page)